# Measuring 240V on earth wire

Tags: voltage, earth, shock

One of our breakers was tripping every few minutes (which powers an air-pump and a few 12V solenoid valves.)

I went to measure the voltages and everything seemed fine.

As I went over and touched the air-pump's on-off switch, I got a nasty shock from the little metal rim sitting around the switch toggle.

I proceeded to measure the voltage between the earth wire and the physical dirt beneath my feet and measured 240V.

Why is earth sitting at 240V?

A qualified electrician installed the setup, so I'm not too sure what's causing this. Ideas?

Comment: Something has gone wrong. Call the electrician you used.

Comment: Faulty earthing. It is dangerous

Comment: One question, before the breaker trips, please tell us measured voltage between earth and "little metal rim"

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's a earth wire, doesn't mean it actually is earthed.  It could be that the wiring is damaged, or that somebody forgot to connect it at all.

Sometimes, the only solution is to install a temporary earth rod, separate from the electrical system, and keep measuring the voltages between that and different parts of the installation's "earth" until you find where the break is.